# Google Translate from Java Application

Tags: java, http-status-code-403, google-translate

I am trying to do a simple translator by NetBeans. Firstly, I tried to implement the code below from a forum page:(https://www.java-forums.org/java-applets/38563-language-translation.html)

```
import com.google.api.translate.Language;
import com.google.api.translate.Translate;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Set the HTTP referrer to your website address.
        Translate.setHttpReferrer("http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java");

        String translatedText = Translate.execute("Bonjour monde le",
                Language.FRENCH, Language.ENGLISH);

        System.out.println(translatedText);
    }
}
```

I cannot compile the code. I got cannot resolve symbol for setHttpReferrer() although I added related jar.

Secondly, I tried to implement another solution from the page (https://www.java-forums.org/java-applets/61655-language-translation-using-google-api.html). I got my API key and set it.

```
import com.google.api.GoogleAPI;
import com.google.api.translate.Language;
import com.google.api.translate.Translate;

public class Translation
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
GoogleAPI.setHttpReferrer("http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java");
GoogleAPI.setKey("i have set my Api key");
String translatedText = Translate.DEFAULT.execute("Bonjour le monde", Language.FRENCH, Language.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(translatedText);
}
}
```

When I try to run this I got `403` error as null. Is there a simple way to call Google Translator from Java application?

Comment: You very likely need an API key for this. Google doesn't just let anyone hit their API endpoints freely

Comment: I think I cannot use it as free?

Comment: What I mean is that you can use it for free. You need an API key to access the service. There's more official documentation for Google Translate than a random forum post

Comment: Infact I set my own API key at this line GoogleAPI.setKey("i have set my Api key");

Comment: Again, stop copying code line for line from random forum posts. `"i have set my Api key"` is not a **Google provided** key. That's not a string you just set yourself. You need a Google developer account, which would be made clear from the official documentation

Comment: Start here. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-translate/README.md

Comment: Of course I set my API key I did not share it here. I mean I got my own API key but when I repeated the steps at that link I got:{
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Google Cloud Translation API has not been used in project composed-world-before or it is disabled.
       "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }

Answer (score 1):

403 error is documented on the faq as "exceeding your quota". https://cloud.google.com/translate/faq

I suspect however, you get the error because you haven't initialised the API properly, i.e authenticated, ...

Have a look at the setup in this code. Also search for hello welt.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-translate/src/test/java/com/google/cloud/translate/TranslateImplTest.java

Hope this helps.